# ios how to set color for a specific string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

Today I got a New Task. Which is to create a singleton class to set colour for the app according to the given value. For an example if i want to set background_Colour, i have to achive this from following code.

> [[ ThemeManager SharedInstance] setcolor:background_Colour]

But i have to have different values`(EX: labelColor, FontColor)` in My singletonClass.
so far i have created the singleton class. but i dont know how to achieve this task. Can anyone help me? Here what i tried So far.

ThemeManager.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ThemeManager : NSObject

+(instancetype)sharedInstance;

-(nullable UIColour *)setcolor:(NSString *)Colour;

@end
```

ThemeManager.m

```
#import "DAThemManager.h"

@implementation DAThemManager{
    UIColor *_customColor;
}

+(instancetype)sharedInstance{
    static id sharedManagerInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedManagerInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedManagerInstance;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

-(nullable UIColour *)setcolor:(NSString *)Colour{

   // i dont know what to implement here 
   // _customColor = [UIColor:redColour key:background_Colour];

    return _customColor ;
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you using storyboard or XIB - In that case it's not possible.You have to be add component by code.

Comment: yup. exactly i added all the component using code.

Answer (score 0):

To customize the appearance of all instances of a class, use appearance to get the appearance proxy for the class. For example, to modify the bar background tint color for all instances of UINavigationBar:
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:myNavBarBackgroundColor];
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance

if the string value formatter is hex,you can use:

```
+ (UIColor *)colorWithHexString:(NSString *)color alpha:(CGFloat)alpha {
NSString *cString = [[color stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] uppercaseString];
// String should be 6 or 8 characters
if ([cString length] < 6)
{
    return [UIColor clearColor];
}
// strip 0X if it appears
if ([cString hasPrefix:@"0X"])
{
    cString = [cString substringFromIndex:2];
}

if ([cString hasPrefix:@"#"])
{
    cString = [cString substringFromIndex:1];
}
if ([cString length] != 6)
{
    return [UIColor clearColor];
}

// Separate into r, g, b substrings
NSRange range;
range.location = 0;
range.length = 2;
//r
NSString *rString = [cString substringWithRange:range];
//g
range.location = 2;
NSString *gString = [cString substringWithRange:range];
//b
range.location = 4;
NSString *bString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

// Scan values
unsigned int r, g, b;
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:rString] scanHexInt:&r];
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:gString] scanHexInt:&g];
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:bString] scanHexInt:&b];
return [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)r / 255.0f) green:((float)g / 255.0f) blue:((float)b / 255.0f) alpha:alpha];
```

}

Comment: Sorry, This not the answer for what i asked,

Comment: sorry bro you just trying to set colour value for hexString. I dont want that, i just need to set the values for a given string. No need to user those prefix such a things,

Answer (score 0):

- So Now First add Contant.h Header file by using
  New file --> (ios,Source)Header file. Create one file.

  - Add this line before #endif

> `#define RP_GREEN_COLOR              [UIColor colorWithRed:62/255.0 green:156/255.0 blue:133/255.0 alpha:1];` // Your color is here

- Now create PrefixHeader.pch file.
  New file --> (ios,Other)PCH file.
- Also add PCH file name in Target --> build setting ---> Prefix header
  Like - yourProjectName/PrefixHeader.pch
- Import you constant file in .pch file before #endif
- Now you can use any variable throughout the project that define in Constant file.You need to change it only one place.

[image]

You can Use this -

> `self.view.backgroundColor = RP_GREEN_COLOR;`